# In index allocation scheme, what parameters does the maximum size of a file depends on?

Tags: database-theory, databases

My understanding is as follows:

```
Number of address entries in one index block (A) = Block size / Address size
Total address entries (B) = Number of index blocks * (A)
File size = Block size * (B)
```

So, we must know the **block size**, **block address size**, and **the number of index blocks** to find the file size. However the sites I've looked at say that file size can be calculated from just the index size and number of index blocks.

- https://interviewmania.com/discussion/91851-database-database-miscellaneous
- [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2002-question-47/#:~:text=When%20indexes%20are%20created%2C%20the,option%20(B)%20is%20correct](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2002-question-47/#:%7E:text=When%20indexes%20are%20created%2C%20the,option%20(B)%20is%20correct).
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugc-net-ugc-net-cs-2015-jun-iii-question-12/

Are they wrong or am I missing something?